# Can't use Fancybox2 in Magento. Error: " Uncaught TypeError ... has no method ... "

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, fancybox

I've included fancybox2 files like instructed here
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#instructions
using my extensions xml and 
`<action method="addJs">` 
for javascript files and 
`<action method="addItem">` 
for css.

Order of my included js and css files inside my :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="magento/js/calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="magento/js/n123/fancybox2/source/jquery.fancybox.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="magento/skin/frontend/default/default/css/styles.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="magento/skin/frontend/base/default/css/widgets.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="magento/skin/frontend/default/default/css/print.css" media="print" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="magento/js/prototype/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="magento/js/lib/ccard.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="magento/js/prototype/validation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="magento/js/scriptaculous/builder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="magento/js/scriptaculous/effects.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="magento/js/scriptaculous/dragdrop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="magento/js/scriptaculous/controls.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="magento/js/scriptaculous/slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="magento/js/varien/js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="magento/js/varien/form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="magento/js/varien/menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="magento/js/mage/translate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="magento/js/mage/cookies.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="magento/js/n123/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="magento/js/n123/jquery/jquery.no.conflict.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="magento/js/varien/product.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="magento/js/varien/configurable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="magento/js/calendar/calendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="magento/js/calendar/calendar-setup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="magento/js/n123/fancybox2/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
```

Then inside my template (phtml) I've added following code:

```
<a id="single_1" href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7100/6917703112_d18e3e1b95_b.jpg" title="Assunção - Santo Tirso...a New Dimension... (Alex Matos)">
<img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7100/6917703112_d18e3e1b95_m.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#single_1").fancybox({
          helpers: {
              title : {
                  type : 'float'
              }
          }
      });
</script>
```

In Chrome this error occurs:

http://www.imagebanana.com/view/6oxxttnx/s02.png

```
       Uncaught TypeError: Object function wrap(wrapper) {
             var __method = this;
             return function() 
                       {
                          var a = update([__method.bind(this)],  arguments) ;
                          return wrapper.apply(this, a);
                       }
       } has no method 'unbind'
```

Every help is welcome!

Comment: Added through `code` <script type="text/javascript" src="magento/js/n123/jquery/jquery.no.conflict.js"></script>

Comment: you sure this error is created by fancybox? ... when does the error occurs? ....your code above isn't properly wrapped, is this just an unintentional omission?

Comment: chrome says that this error is caused by jquery.fancybox.pack.js.
pls take a look at the new screenshot: http://www.imagebanana.com/view/6oxxttnx/s02.png
code is wrapped in my project. it was a copy & paste problem ;)
do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a soulution: in my case the packed "fancybox.pack.js" didn't work and I got that error posted above but the "fancybox.js" ("unpacked"/normal version) works like a charm! Thanks for your support and attention.